# parse tarball stream for specific file in node.js

Tags: node.js, stream, tar

Using node.js, I would like to process a large tarball sequentially, looking for a specific file. Once encountered, I'd like to save the file then quit processing the rest of the tarball. This would result in a much quicker response as I would not have to wait for the whole file to be processed.

I have got some code that uses streaming 'tar' package in the node.js repository, as follows:

```
fs.createReadStream('mytarball.tar.gz')
.on('error', console.log)
.pipe(zlib.Unzip())
.pipe(tar.Parse())
.on('entry', function(entry) {
    if(entry.path == 'myfile') {
        console.log('found myfile');

        // save file
        entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(entry.path));

        //
        // HELP - how do I stop processing the rest of the tarball (gracefully)
        //
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to simply call `close()` on your file stream:

```
var fstream = fs.createReadStream('mytarball.tar.gz')
                .on('error', console.log);
fstream
  .pipe(zlib.Unzip())
  .pipe(tar.Parse())
  .on('entry', function(entry) {
      if(entry.path == 'myfile') {
          console.log('found myfile');

          // save file
          entry.on('end', function() {
            fstream.close();
          }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(entry.path));
      }
  });
```